# UITableViewCell Image not updating

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I can update the detailTextLabel.text and the UITableViewCell shows the changes at runtime, but if I try to update the imageView.image it does not change the visible image. Any idea as to why? I have tried calling a refresh on the UITableViewCell specifically but to no avail.

```
-(void)getImageForURL:(NSURL*)url row:(UITableViewCell*)cell {

    UIImage*image;

    image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    cell.imageView.image = image; // Does not work..
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"test"; // Works

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the cell style is UITableViewCellStyleDefault, because other cell types may always return nil imageView, instead of creating one on demand.

Comment: It is. I am putting a placeholder graphic in initially then calling this function to replace the placeholder in the BG.

Comment: Do you, by chance, reset the image to the placeholder in your data source callback? Maybe, the downloaded image is not what you expect? Check its size and CGImage properties, then. Just for kicks, also check the value of cell.imageView.image before and after the assignment.

Answer (score 22):

Try calling `[cell setNeedsLayout]` after setting the image, if it's the first image you're setting for the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the image is nil or not. If its nil then the Image is not fetched from the URL correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I too was having problems with adding the image to my imageView that was constrained in a tableview cell and was not updating with cell.setNeedsLayout(). Calling update methods on the tableview after the image was added did the trick for me:

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
}
else {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```